# Confusion about whether or not force can be exerted on air

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, forces, fluid-dynamics, drag

If someone is running in air, the air exerts a force on them i.e. air resistance. However, does the person exert a force on the molecules in the air during their motion. It seems very likely to me but I was unable any such thing on the internet. Please tell me where I am going wrong in my thought process.

Comment: Why would you think the person doesn't exert the exact opposite force on the air molecules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! Newton's third law states that:

> For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.

You exert a force of magnitude $F$ on the air, and that air will exert a force of the same magnitude $F$ on you, only the force exerted *by the air* will have the *opposite* direction to the force *you* exerted.

That's how machines like helicopter operate. They 'push' the air around to create a "Lift" force which allows them to fly. Of course, the reality is much more complicated, but air is the reason helicopters and planes do in fact fly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is Newton's third law of motion.

You can realize that when cars (or a quick runner) pass by. You will feel the draft of the air, moving along with the car. This air is set in motion by the car.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as others have answered, when an object exerts a force force on air, the air exerts an equal and opposite force on the object.  Consider a fan; the fan pushes the air and the air pushes back against the fan.  You can feel the effect of the force of the fan on the air as the movement of the air.